# Security: Is the Raspberry Pi really stateless?

Tags: security, raspberry-pi, cryptography

The Raspberry Pi has become very popular. Because it is rather cheap and simple it could be an attractive device for people living in so called developing countries.

However in many of these states it is important for journalists and political activists to have trustworthy devices which can't spy on their users. Conventional PCs contain a lot of hardware components with flash memory. The firmware of these components can be reprogrammed to contain malicious software spying on their users (see paper: [here](http://blog.invisiblethings.org/papers/2015/state_harmful.pdf), talk held December 2015: [here](https://events.ccc.de/congress/2015/Fahrplan/events/7352.html)).

I've tried to research the data sheets of the various chips on Raspberry Pi. But I'm still not sure: Is my conclusion right that (assuming the content of the SD CARD has not been compromised) genuine original Raspberry Pis (A and B and 2) have no chips "on board" suitable for sniffing or spying malware
which could possibly compromise important keys handled on such a system?

Comment: To quote James Mickens 'Basically, you're either dealing with Mossad or not-Mossad. If your adversary is not-Mossad, then you'll probably be fine if you pick a good password and don't respond to emails from ChEaPestPAiNPi11s@virus-basket.biz.ru. If your adversary is the Mossad, YOU'RE GONNA DIE AND THERE'S NOTHING THAT YOU CAN DO ABOUT IT.' Its entirely plausible

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: In your comment you paint the world very black and white. I hope there are some shades of grey inbetween.  Otherwise there would be no need to bother about end-to-end encryption and such.

Comment: Posted a more detailed answer. Nonetheless, you're talking about *theoretical* and very exotic exploits, and considering a device a magic solution to a problem. In addition the problem the rpi would solve for you is much more theoratical than interception of data and/or surveillance by metadata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RPi is wierd. Your bootloader's actually fired up from the GPU, and your arm processor is a co-processor for the GPU. As such the first stage bootloader *is* on a rom, can't be changed, and can be trusted roughly as far as you trust the rpi foundation.

Amusingly this also means you can pretty much never brick a rpi - since the rpi itself, as you say is 'stateless' or more precisely there's no non volatile memory onboard the rpi.

I probably should provide some sources - elinux hosts what is the official rpi wiki I believe - they go into the basics of how the [rpi runs](http://elinux.org/RPi_Software). This [Rpi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7122/level-of-hackability-of-raspberry-pi) goes into how the system is set up and why its 'odd'. This post on [the kandyan code](https://thekandyancode.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/how-the-raspberry-pi-boots-up/) is useful for understanding how the boot process works.

Its worth considering though, while Joanna Rutkowska is a *brilliant* hacker, much of the work she does is with exotic exploits. Its *relatively* unlikely that many of the things she works on would be common and weaponized and the paper feels like a theoratical 'what if' - compare this with the [blue pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_%28software%29) - controversy aside, there's a working example of the exploit.

So in theory a Rpi with a *trusted* install on an SD card that you know hasn't had its firmware tampered with ([Bunny Huang says its possible](http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=3554)) ought to be reasonably trustworthy.

That said, I'd like to suggest two counterpoints to this idea. Against a *truely* repressive regime, the problem isn't just collecting information it is exfiltrating things. It is also far simpler for a regime to tap into communications, or [beat someone with a wrench](https://xkcd.com/538/) than it is to sneak malware into a PC. The second is that if you're dealing with an opponent who is repressive *and* has the technical sophistication to do routine firmware hacks, there's other points of weakness. 'Stateless' devices shouldn't give a false idea of security.

Secondly unless there's a standard issue "political activist laptop", your adversery would need a *wild* array of exploits targetting every single laptop model, or a wide array of drives. Software exploits, and oldshool bugs, and both phone tapping and traffic analysis is cheaper and a better use of resources. Once again, a wrench is cheaper and more effective than cracking your password and traditional intelligence methods are more of a threat than exotic exploits. For that matter, walking around with a rpi and refusing to use other systems might seem a tad bit suspicious if all the cool activists were doing it. I'd rather a disposable burner smartphone bought in a third country with third party firmware if I was a journalist. No one pays attention to those.

That said, the RPI does have a few good points. They are ridiculously cheap, and small, so I guess *if* you needed to run in a hurry, no big loss. Grab your SD card and run. Maybe have some way to destroy the SD cards or swap them out for innocent content. Just remember that technology of any sort is *not* a cure it all.

Comment: Yes the work of Bunny Huang is important in this context. Thanks for your elaborated answer.